# Como definir el ancho de columnas en DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable

tengo el siguiente detalle, estoy mostrando informacion con DataTable, normalmente si se presenta la vista en una pantalla "grande" se ve muy bien la tabla, pero si llevas esa misma imagen a una pantalla mas pequeña se distorsiona un poco la vista dejo ejemplos de las vistas:

[image: Vista de la tabla en pantalla chica]

Y esta es la manera en que se ve en una pantalla mas grande:

[image: Vista de la tabla en pantalla grande]

Lo que quiero hacer de alguna manera pero no me ha funcionado, es reajustar el tamaño de las celdas para que no se empalmen los botones de la ultima celda.

El código que he utilizado para esta y otras dataTables es el siguiente:

Tengo un archivo donde declaro todas las tablas que estoy utilizando a lo largo del proyecto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#miPrimerTabla').DataTable({

            "language": {
                "url": "librerias_auxiliares/Bootstrap/js/español.json",
            }
        }),
            "columnDefs"[
                        { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
                        { "width": "10%", "targets": 1},
                        { "width": "10%", "targets": 2 },
                        { "width": "10%", "targets": 3 },
                        { "width": "50%", "targets": 4 },
                        { "width": "10%", "targets": 5 },
                            { "width": "10%", "targets": 6 },
                            { "width": "10%", "targets": 7 },
                        { "width": "10%", "targets": 8 },
                        { "width": "30%", "targets": 9 }
                        ]

});
```

En otro archivo el que se llama español.json,  tengo la traduccion para que el dataTable se lea en español cada uno de sus componentes

```js
{
    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":            "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Primero",
        "sLast":     "Último",
        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
}
```

Y este es el código de HTML solo voy a poner el cuerpo principal sin datos:

```html
<table id="miPrimerTabla"  class="table table-striped table-bordered  table-responsive dataTable_width_auto display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">#BIEN</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">VALIDACI&Oacute;N</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">ETIQUETA</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">TIPO DE BIEN</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">DESCRIPCIÓN DEL BIEN</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">MARCA</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">MODELO</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">NUMERO DE SERIE</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">ESTATUS DEL ACTIVO</th>
                <th style="font-size:12px; background-color: #FF8200;">ACCIONES:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
         Aquí va todo le código que imprime los datos, validaciones y botones
        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;"># BIEN</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">VALIDACI&Oacute;N</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">ETIQUETA</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">TIPO DE BIEN</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">DESCRIPCION DEL BIEN</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">MARCA</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">MODELO</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">NUMERO DE SERIE</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5CB85C;">ESTATUS DEL ACTIVO</th>
            <th  style="font-size:12px; background-color: #FF8200;">ACCIONES:</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Adicionalmente viendo un ejemplo que encontré aquí mismo en stackoverflow agregue unas lineas a un CSS pero no ha sido suficiente:  `table.dataTable.dataTable_width_auto { width: auto; }`  y bueno la respectiva linea al momento de llamar a la tabla:

```
<table id="miPrimerTabla"  class="table table-striped table-bordered  table-responsive dataTable_width_auto display" style="width:100%">
```

basado en un ejemplo :[Ejemplo encontrado previamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146118/datatables-no-consigo-modificar-el-ancho-de-las-columnas/146137)  y adicionalmente leyendo el foro de dataTable y algunas otras aportaciones pero no logro que me funcione.

Agradezco cualquier aportación que me ayude a resolver este detalle.